# Using JavaScript Event rather than MooTools Element.Event

Tags: javascript, scope, mootools, dom-events

I have inherited a codebase which implements MooTools 1.4.5.

The code also utilises a third party library to handle dragging on responsive devices. The following code is in that library:

```
var dndEvent = new Event(type, {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: cancelable
});
```

That event is producing the following exception in an anonymous MooTools function:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

The MooTools code is minified (and unmapped), so as yet I have not tested it against the unminified code to see what this anonymous function does, but I suspect it is related to MooTools [Element.Event](https://mootools.net/core/docs/1.4.5/Element/Element.Event).

If this is the case how would I force the scope to use JavaScript's Event interface rather than MooTools?

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack (as I think you're trying to avoid deep refactoring at this stage) would be to 'save' the Event object before Mootools overwrites it:

```
<script>window.savedEvent = window.Event</script>
<script src="mootools.js"></script>
```

And then modify your 3rd party library to use 'savedEvent' where it now says 'Event', or place all of it inside a scope..

```
+(function() {
  var Event = window.savedEvent
  //existing code goes here
})()
```

but that might require you to explicitly export everything that library offers by putting those identifiers on the window object